# AngularJS Setting Input from Select

Tags: angularjs, select, input, selected

How would you go about having data that's selected in a select, populate an input form?

Code so far:

```
<form class="form-horizontal well" role="form" novalidate name="editSomeForm" ng-init="getSomeNames()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Some Name: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="some.name" ng-options="s.name for s in data.some_names"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="someId" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Some ID: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="someId" name="someId" ng-model="some.id"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

js:

```
app.controller('EditSomething', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getSomeNames = function() {
    $http.get('/api/something/editinfo').
      success(function (data) {
        $scope.some.name = data.some_names[0];
        $scope.data = data;
      }).
      error(function (data){
        $scope.some_names = {}
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the ng-model of the input field to be the same as the select field, but bear in mind that this is 'two-way'. If you change the input field, it will attempt to change the select field.

Another approach is to add an `ng-change` attribute and have it fire a scope function that assigns the data to another scope variable